# TypeScript 3.9.5- The intersection '...' was reduced to 'never' because property 'usage' has conflicting types in some constituents

Tags: typescript

I have a function which take in a class definition and uses that to return a new abstract class. Up to TS v3.8.3 this worked fine. Now while upgrading to TS v3.9.5 Typescript appears to be getting a different type from the class passed into the function. It's best if I just reproduce the code here.

```
enum AttributeUsageModel {
  ContractHash = 0x00,
  ECDH02 = 0x02,
  ECDH03 = 0x03,
  Script = 0x20,
  Vote = 0x30,
  DescriptionUrl = 0x81,
  Description = 0x90,
  Hash1 = 0xa1,
  Hash2 = 0xa2,
  Hash3 = 0xa3,
  Hash4 = 0xa4,
  Hash5 = 0xa5,
}

type BufferAttributeUsageModel =
  | 0x81
  | 0x90
  | 0xf0
  | 0xfa
  | 0xfb
  | 0xfc
  | 0xfd
  | 0xfe
  | 0xff;

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

abstract class AttributeBaseModel<T extends AttributeUsageModel> {
  public abstract readonly usage: T;
}

class AttributeModel extends AttributeBaseModel<BufferAttributeUsageModel> {
  public readonly usage: BufferAttributeUsageModel;

  public constructor(usage: BufferAttributeUsageModel) {
    super();
    this.usage = usage;
  }
}

function AttributeBase<
  Usage extends AttributeUsageModel,
  TBase extends Constructor<AttributeBaseModel<Usage>>
>(Base: TBase) {
  // Replacing `Base` with `AttributeModel` apparently fixes it
  abstract class AttributeBaseClass extends Base {} // Base constructor return type is apparently 'never'

  return AttributeBaseClass;
}

// Base constructor return type 'never' is not an object type or intersection of object types with
// statically known members.
//   The intersection 'AttributeBase<AttributeUsageModel, typeof
//   AttributeModel>.AttributeBaseClass & AttributeModel' was
//   reduced to 'never' because property 'usage' has conflicting types in some constituents.
class BufferAttribute extends AttributeBase(AttributeModel) {
  public constructor(usage: BufferAttributeUsageModel) {
    super(usage);
  }
}
```

The error from Typescript is highlighted on `AttributeBase(AttributeModel)`. In this example `AttributeModel` is being passed into the function as the `Base` argument. If we use `AttributeModel` directly inside the function instead of the `Base` argument the error goes away. But this is the same thing, right?

I'm not an expert in Typescript yet, but we do need some way to use this `AttributeBase` function, or some other method, to dynamically extend multiple base classes. Perhaps the answer is obvious, but this does seem like rather odd behavior. I've tried a bunch of other things but nothing that maintains the same type strictness we get from this setup.

So can someone please explain to me what's going on here and how I might fix this so we get the same type safety without the `never` return type from `AttributeBase(AttributeModel)`?

I've also posted this code to a repo [here](https://github.com/spencercorwin/ts-never/blob/master/index.ts) if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that your `BufferAttributeUsageModel` does not extend `AttributeUsageModel`.

Your `AttributeBaseModel<T extends AttributeUsageModel>` requires `T extends AttributeUsageModel`, but then you define `class AttributeModel extends AttributeBaseModel<BufferAttributeUsageModel>` with `BufferAttributeUsageModel` that does not extend `AttributeUsageModel`. That's where your `usage` property "has conflicting types in some constituents." - as the error states.

To fix that, you can define `BufferAttributeUsageModel` as:

```js
type BufferAttributeUsageModel =
    AttributeUsageModel
    | 0x81
    | 0x90
    | 0xf0
    | 0xfa
    | 0xfb
    | 0xfc
    | 0xfd
    | 0xfe
    | 0xff;
```

Perhaps, you should try to simplify those type definitions.

Comment: Thank you! This is solves my problem. The numbers in `BufferAttributeUsageModel` are all contained within the `enum` `AttributeUsageModel` so I can keep the stricter type safety by defining the `BufferAttributeUsageModel` as a union between the necessary members of the `AttributeUsageModel` enum (and do the same elsewhere). Just writing this out for anyone else who finds this.